# Access string in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, string, series

I have a csv table with a column (tags) full of lists of strings. To convert it to a pd series I used

```
 def flatten(series):
  return pd.Series(series.dropna().sum())

tags_sorted = flatten(df['tags'])
```

Now I want to search the series for a string within one of the lists so that it returns the number of times that string occurs within the column. I found this function:

```
def find(series, tag):
  for i in series.index:
    if series[i] == tag: 
        return i
return None
```

and used it on my series:

```
 print(find(tags_sorted, 'romance'))
```

but it keeps returning `None` even though the string is definitely in multiple lists.

I also tried

```
print(tags_sorted[tags_sorted == "romance"])
```

and

```
print(tags_sorted.loc[tags_sorted == 'romance'])
```

but those only return `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that you need to change find function to:

```
def find(series, tag):
    times_occurred = 0

    for i in series.index:
        if series[i] == tag:
            times_occurred += 1

    return times_occurred
```

, if you want to find how many times the specific string occurred.

Comment: That makes sense! The function returns 0 now though, so it still has trouble matching the string within the list with the given string :/

Comment: There is an example of what I tested and seemed to work: 
`df = pd.DataFrame([[1, ["a", "b", "c"]], [2, ["c", "d"]], [3, ["a", "d", "e"]]], columns=["id", "tags"])`
There I create a simple dataframe for testing purposes. And then used `tags_sorted = flatten(df['tags'])` and finally `print(find(tags_sorted, "a"))` command prints 2. So it seems to be working for me.